# Why symbols are prefixed with an underscore in compiled files?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, object-files, nm

The following page says **On OSX, these are prefixed with an underscore.** Is there a reason why an underscore has to be added? Why not just use the original function names? Thanks.

http://nickdesaulniers.github.io/blog/2016/08/13/object-files-and-symbols/

Comment: Not enough info for a full answer, especially since you ask about OSX, but take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C